# Views Results - Display specific user

Tags: views, webforms

I have created a view based off the webform submission data.  So if [Mary] has submitted five forms, and [Julie] has submitted three and [Steve] has submitted 8--  When they look at my results page, I only want julie to see her rows/submission info, Mary should only see her five rows and steve his 8.

The users are authenticated users so they have to login to complete the form and I capture their user and other personal info and of course to access the results page they must me authenticated as well.

I thought getting the submission data layed out in the view was going to be the hard part.  I want the user to click on a link to "previous submissions" and when the results page opens, only their rows appear.  I know the query will be return all the rows where the userID matches the userID of the currently logged in user.

I'm thinking this is hard because I am using webform submission data versus typical views of regular content.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your view:

- Create the relationship "Webform Submissions: User" and require it
- Create the contextual filter "User: uid" and select the relationship you created at the top and select "provide Default Value" under "When the value is NOT in the URL"
- Save

And you're done!

If you have the the contextual filter already you must delete it and create it again.

Comment: This was the key [If you have the the contextual filter already you must delete it and create it again.]  thanks so much!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sound any different to displaying content as long as you can access the uid you have stored in 'filters'.

Set up a *relationship* from the data you wish to display to the person who created the data and then make a filter for 'author uid' (or similar) = 'current user uid'.  You will probably need to use tokens for the right side of that equation.